# SSIS JOB FAILING BECAUSE IT CONNECTING TO A MYSQL CONNECTION

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis

I have a package that takes data from a MYSQL source and load the data to a MSSQL DB. The package runs well when i run on it on ssis manually but since i convert it to a deployement model and run it with my server agent, the job kept on failling.
My Guess is maybe for some reasons the server agent cannot connect to the the MYSQL source using the connection parameters

1. i have tried to run the package as 32-bit
2. try to use odbc connection to mysql instead of the ADO.NET i use initially

Comment: Post the error. Changing drivers won't fix a bad connection string, a closed firewall or wrong credentials. The error messages should tell you what actually happened

Comment: My first suspicion would be credentials/authentication. Have you been able to manually run it from the same machine where the server agent is running? That would eliminate drivers & connection string.

Comment: Typically this is due to the so called security hardening where some communications are intentionally blocked by port and destination. So your local machine may not have the same hardening applied, but a firewall works for where the serer resides.